# OpenGl drag square

Tags: android, opengl-es, vertex

I'm creating a curtain like animation triggered by onTouchEvent() where u can drag one end of a square to make it bigger or smaller.
My only problem is that instead of having a square on the entire screen, I get a small line on the top of the screen and i can expand and de-expand that line.
Why won't this code draw a square?

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    float ratio = (float) width / height;
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);        // set matrix to projection mode
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                        // reset the matrix to its default state    
    gl.glOrthof(0, height, width, 0, -3, 8);

}
```

Vertices:

```
private float vertices[] = { 
          -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  // 0, Top Left
          -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  // 1, Bottom Left
           1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  // 2, Bottom Right
           1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  // 3, Top Right

};

// The order we like to connect them.
private short[] indices = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };
```

And the draw method in Square:

```
public void draw(GL10 gl,float x,float y) {
    // Counter-clockwise winding.
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW); // OpenGL docs
    //Point to our vertex buffer
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    //Enable vertex buffer
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);
    //Draw the vertices as triangle strip
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);
    //Disable the client state before leaving
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing this? after setting the projection mode.

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);        // set modelview matrix to identity.
gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

Comment: can you try getting rid of the     gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW); // OpenGL docs